# How to query OSB (ALSB) service bus messages?

Tags: alsb, osb

Is it possible to use the OSB JMX interface to query the messages going through the service bus?

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually want to log the message into log files? If yes, I would recommend to try OSB existing "trace" feature which is configurable in osb console.

Comment: I want to be able to follow the message from source to destination, and the content of the message